# Cómo acceder a mi aplicación REST desplegada con Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

Estoy realizando una guía sobre desarrollar una aplicación REST en Spring. Todo ha ido bien y logré desplegarla sin errores, el problema es que no encuentro a que URL acceder para probar las peticiones. Existe algun fichero de configuración en el maven (estoy usando 7.0.47) o dentro del IDE (Intellij IDEA 2018) donde pueda encontrar a que URL ha desplegado la aplicación?

Las clases de configuración de la aplicación son:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{ ApplicationConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/rest/"};
}
```

}

y

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "yam")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

Y mi clase controladora es:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/payment")
public class PaymentController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pay", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public BaseResponse pay(@RequestParam(value = "key") String key, @RequestBody PaymentRequest request) {
        //Lógica del método...
    }
}
```

Cuando corro el Tomcat me abre en el navegador la siguiente dirección:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

y porsupuesto muestra un **404**

Este es lo que muestra Tomcat Catalina Log:

```
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\TotalCommander2017\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;.
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 408 ms
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 40 ms
abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFORMACIÓN: validateJarFile(C:\Users\myuser\IdeaProjects\out\artifacts\tracker_artifact\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
abr 12, 2018 3:10:42 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFORMACIÓN: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
abr 12, 2018 3:10:42 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMACIÓN: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Apr 12 15:10:42 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
abr 12, 2018 3:10:42 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMACIÓN: Registering annotated classes: [class yam.config.ApplicationConfiguration]
abr 12, 2018 3:10:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFORMACIÓN: Mapped "{[/payment/pay],methods=[POST]}" onto public yam.model.BaseResponse yam.controller.PaymentController.pay(java.lang.String,yam.model.PaymentRequest)
abr 12, 2018 3:10:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFORMACIÓN: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Apr 12 15:10:42 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
abr 12, 2018 3:10:43 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFORMACIÓN: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1268 ms
abr 12, 2018 3:10:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFORMACIÓN: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
abr 12, 2018 3:10:43 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMACIÓN: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Apr 12 15:10:43 EDT 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
abr 12, 2018 3:10:43 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFORMACIÓN: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 51 ms
abr 12, 2018 3:10:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio D:\Apps\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\manager de la aplicación web
```

Comment: Que te muestra el log en tomcat puedes verlo sera mas facil asi ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

si lo que falta es solo el url

Lo que puedes hacer es buscar en el pom.xml, el contenido de los tag artifactId + version y lo unes.

ejm:

```
<artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
```

Obtienes el principal

http://localhost:8080/MyApp1

Luego le agregas tu servicio y la operación

http://localhost:8080/MyApp1/payment/pay

Comment: Mis tags: <artifactId>yam</artifactId> y <version>1</version> probe con la url: localhost:8080/yam1/payment/pay/??key=value y sigue mostrando un 404.

Comment: @Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/rest/"};
}
Según este método intenta con
localhost:8080/yam1/rest/payment/pay

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el **error** de:

> La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\TotalCommander2017\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;.
>   abr 12, 2018 3:10:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

Lo que tienes que hacer es bajar los `tomcat-connectors` en este [link](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/1.1.22/binaries/win32/) dependiendo si es 32 o 64 bits tu pc, luego lo pegas en agregarlo al `c:\windows\system32\`, si quieres leer mas sobre este error te dejo el link de la pagina oficial de  [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html)